# How to set large data on spinner

Tags: android, api

I am new in android development. An interviewer asked me a question that how would you set the large amount of data on a spinner. Data is on server which is very large, for example one million strings. How would you set in on a spinner so that user doesn't have to wait much in order to load that data?

I try to find this kind of question here but i didn't get expected answer so i have posted here.

Comment: I mean data is comming from server, for example one million strings i have to set on a spinner.

Comment: You should've told them that it's not a good idea to show one millions strings in a spinner. It doesn't make sense and user won't scroll to even 10% of the items.

Comment: So what's the alternative? If there is the requirement like this.

Comment: try implementing a custom spinner using recyclerview(with pagination)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store large amount of data in arraylist, ArrayList in Java has a get(int index) method.  int is a signed 32 bit value, with a maximum value of 2,147,483,647. You can therefore store about 2.14 billion records in an arraylist.

then you can display arraylist in spinner recycleview. The RecyclerView is much more powerful, flexible. it doesn't freezes the UI. It supports the use Viewholder pattern and can contains 100k+ rows it runs very smooth.

Comment: But what about loading time from remote server?

Comment: Since data is string only, it can be loaded in few seconds. 1 mb speed can fetch upto 1 million characters.

Comment: There could be more efficient and faster way to load data. But that's what i had in mind and i thought it might help.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

Simply implement pagination and load the data in chunks. If the API isn't enhanced for pagination, download the strings and set them to an ArrayList, then paginate the array by looping through and receiving the data